# Cannot import class from other file

Tags: python

I have a file in which I want to import a class. Structure is as follows:

```
- models\
-- User.py
-- Role.py
app.py
```

File `User.py` looks like this:

```
from flask_security import UserMixin
from app import db


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
                           db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
                           db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
                           )

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

In my `app.py` I do:

```
from models.User import User
```

And then I am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/app/app.py", line 7, in <module>
     from models.User import User
   File "/var/app/models/User.py", line 2, in <module>
     from app import db
   File "/var/app/app.py", line 7, in <module>
     from models.User import User
ImportError: cannot import name 'User'
```

What should I do? When I declare class `User` in `app.py`, all works good.

Comment: `from models import User`

Comment: @UmangGupta this actually works, but now I have other problem with the class. `module 'models.User' has no attribute 'query'`. It worked when class wasn't imported.

Comment: @UmangGupta, while the import may work, what you're doing is importing the module itself. OP wants to import the class from the module.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski, your traceback is not the same case that you've given us: `from models.user import User` (lowercase 'user'). Should it be `from models.User import User`? Also, you'll need the `__init__.py` from root-kidz' answer.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Right, I made a mistake, fixed now. `__init.py__` doesn't help.

Comment: Perhaps this is due to the circular import?

Comment: Oooh, yes because your `User.py` is trying to import from `app.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see your problem, in the first time did not pay attention to the User.py code, but your problem is that from the `app.py` file you try import to the `User.py` file but from the `User.py` you also try to import something "db" from the `app.py` file, that is causing the problem, you are first creating a recursion, second `app.py` is not found in the sys.path therefore when you import `User.py` this tries to import `app.py` but `app.py` is not found.
to solve this problem you should aggravate to the `sys.path` the path of your project and then a file `__init__.py` so you can perform the import in the way you want, but I would recommend that you try to import db from another way.

but you can do this: 
`-your_project/
             |- app.py
             |- __init__.py
             |- model/
                     |- __init__.py
                     |- User.py
                     |- another.py`

them you try:
open a terminal with python inse of your_project

`>>> import sys`

`>>> sys.path.insert(0, '../')`

`>>> import app`

and in app.py the code `from model.User import User` and in User.py `from your_project.app import db`

but I advised against this way it is better that you do a good restructuring of your project and avoid these inconveniences

Comment: You are absolutely right, tomorrow I will restructure my project so that `db` would be in a separate file. But then it will import `app`, because this is the main file in which I am creating everything... Well, nevertheless, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that model is a directory and python does not interpret it as a package, so you can not import anything from it, to solve it you should create a new file within model called `__init__.py` and this file should be blank and this Python will recognize your model as a package

your directory structure should look like this:

```
- model/
       |__ __init__.py
       |__ User.py
       |__ Role.py
- app.py
```

them you can import it, them you can read more about this [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help.

Comment: ohhh yes i'm sorry, I forgot the __init__.py

Comment: No, I did add `__init__.py` inside the directory, didn't help.